# How to access the newly created application's ObjectId from AzureAD v2 cmdlet for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to get the most recent `ObjectId` for a newly created application in `AzureAD v2 cmdlet for PowerShell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the PowerShell cmdlet `New-AzureADApplication` will be the Application object, including the `ObjectId` attribute:

```bsh
PS C:\> New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "My Special App" -IdentifierUris @("https://localhost/my-special-app")
```

```
ObjectId                             AppId                                DisplayName
--------                             -----                                ----------
4a9c0714-adf9-42f4-9189-a69fa2c33861 0f6b4c20-957a-4c96-b477-5562995fd920 My Special App
```

The best way to use do this in your script is to place the result in a variable:

```bsh
PS C:\> $app = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "My Special App" -IdentifierUris @("https://localhost/my-special-app")
PS C:\> $app.ObjectId
```

```
4a9c0714-adf9-42f4-9189-a69fa2c33861
```

If you're looking for the `ObjectId` of an Application object which already exists, you would search for it by name:

```bsh
PS C:\> Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "My"
```

```
ObjectId                             AppId                                DisplayName
--------                             -----                                -----------
4a9c0714-adf9-42f4-9189-a69fa2c33861 0f6b4c20-957a-4c96-b477-5562995fd920 My Special App
4254aa16-b04d-4ce8-9d0b-9b439984499a a4dfe0f4-4406-4906-af67-7201aef85db7 My Other Special App
```

(Note: The `-SearchString` parameter does "startswith" searches, not "contains".)